# Swift - How to declare a private nested struct?

Tags: swift, struct, nested, private

I want o make my code more readable, so I decided to make some repeated dictionary keys, soft coded... So I created a new `.swift` file, with 2 structs in it:

```
struct DatabaseTableNames {
    let Photo = PhotoTable()
}

private struct PhotoTable {
    let lowQuality = "lowQuality"
    let highQuality = "highQuality"
    let numberOfLikes = "numberOfLikes"
}
```

So I have the initial struct I'm gonna use and the second one, which I don't want it to be visible outside of the file's scope... The thing is, it says that the `Photo` property of the `DatabaseTableNames` struct, needs to be declared as `fileprivate` since `PhotoTable` is `private`...

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Will it work to make DatabaseTableNames.Photo private?

Comment: @MobileDan Then it says that "the 'Photo' property is inaccessible due to private protection level"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key was to nest PhotoTable and make its properties static.

```
struct DatabaseTableNames {
    struct PhotoTable {
        static let lowQuality = "lowQuality"
        static let highQuality = "highQuality"
        static let numberOfLikes = "numberOfLikes"
    }
}
```

Example Use:

```
let test = DatabaseTableNames.PhotoTable.lowQuality
print(test)
```

Comment: Then it says that "the 'Photo' property is inaccessible due to fileprivate protection level"

Comment: `static` means it is not an instance property. If you create an instance of PhotoTable it will not contain references to its static properties. You can only access it via DatabaseTableNames.PhotoTable.lowQuality.

Comment: So `let dbTableNames = DatabaseTableNames; print(dbTableNames.lowQuality)` is not possible?

Comment: I think you mean this: let photoTable = DatabaseTableNames.PhotoTable(); print(photoTable.lowQuality), and it does not compile.

Comment: "Static member 'lowQuality' cannot be used on instance of type 'DatabaseTableNames.PhotoTable'"

Comment: Ok! Thank you very much!

Comment: I am assuming this is the behavior you are looking for. I use this technique frequently to give a namespace-like organization to constants.

Comment: So, the following would compile and run but `photoTable` would have no properties and would be useless: `let photoTable = DatabaseTableNames.PhotoTable()`

Answer (score 1):

swap around your `private` settings - and make sure this is defined in the same file as the UIViewController you want to use it

```
private struct DatabaseTableNames {
    let Photo = PhotoTable()
}

struct PhotoTable {
    let lowQuality = "lowQuality"
    let highQuality = "highQuality"
    let numberOfLikes = "numberOfLikes"
}
```

and then, access the struct

```
private var photo : DatabaseTableNames?
```

Comment: But I want to have the "DatabaseTableNames" accessed by all my other classes, not just one...

Comment: if the only variable within the struct is hidden, then what are you sharing with other files?

Comment: That's the thing! I want to be able to use for example: "DatabaseTableNames.Photo.lowQuality" from every other file, but I don't want to be able to access the "PhotoTable" struct directly...